# How to make Pycharm raise warning for setting non existing attributes

Tags: python, class, types, pycharm, static-analysis

In Pycharm, I get the following warning when I get a field that does not exists in a class.

[image]

However, no warning when a field set. `xyz`

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, bar):
        self.bar = bar
        
foo = Foo("bar")
print(foo.bar) # No warning
print(foo.baz)  # Warning: Unresolved attribute reference 'baz' for class 'Foo'
foo.xyz = "xyz" # how to raise a warning for this saying that xyz does not exist in Foo?
```

This is potentially a bug, how to make Pycharm warn for this

Comment: Why is this potentially a bug? It's fairly common to set attributes like that, a PyCharm warning would be more annoying than anything.

Comment: Because Foo is a class, not a dictionary. In an objected oriented approach, this is a bug

Comment: Unless the class specifically prohibits it, with e.g. `__slots__` or a custom `__setattr__`, there's nothing necessarily bugged about adding an attribute in an instance namespace like this.